# How do I persuade people?

Tags: pc, mount-and-blade

I'm playing the original Mount & Blade and have thrice gotten the quest to collect money from one of the other lords. In this, it usually starts out at an astronomical number to pay them to collect, and you can persuade them (or use relationship) to reduce the number.

I am level 25 and have 22 Charisma and 3 persuasion, but I seem to fail more often than not; By failing I mean that the amount of direms I am to pay them goes up. Am I using the persuasion skill wrong, or is it a RNG issue? It seems like my persuasion checks don't really matter when it comes to my charisma.

**How do I persuade the lords to reduce the amount to pay for collection?**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can only answer based on my hours and experience with Mount and Blade: Warband. Hopefully most of this can adapt.

Firstly, three persuasion isn't a whole lot. Try getting it at least above four, I'd say. I usually try to level up the Charisma skills (leadership, trading, persuasion, etc) before any others, including strength, as Charisma is such an important part of the game.

Secondly, and this is probably more relevant, all lords have different personalities. This means that some are less likely to be persuaded than others.

Thirdly, it should also depend on your relationship with them. A higher relationship means it is easier to persuade them, and sometimes with a high enough relationship you might have special options (such as to make a sacrifice because you two have a great relationship, but this may drop relations. I'm also not sure if this occurs in the original M&B).